# Issue While Running Android Emulator

Tags: cordova, android-emulator, phonegap-plugins

I am working on `Cordova` mobile app (using visual studio). It was working fine in the emulator.  But now, I am getting the error below while running in the emulator.  Someone please suggest a solution...

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1    DEMO_APP        1   
Error       java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0  DEMO_APP        1   
Error        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)   DEMO_APP        1   
Error        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) DEMO_APP        1   
Error        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) DEMO_APP        1   
Error        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)    DEMO_APP        1   
Error        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)  DEMO_APP        1   
Error        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)  DEMO_APP        1   
Error        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)  DEMO_APP        1   
Error        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  DEMO_APP        1   
Error        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)  DEMO_APP        1   
Error        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)   DEMO_APP        1   
Error        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)   DEMO_APP        1   
Error        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)   DEMO_APP        1   
Error        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)   DEMO_APP        1   
Error       Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M   DEMO_APP        1   
Error       Exception in thread "main"  DEMO_APP        1   
Error       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.    DEMO_APP        1   
Error       * What went wrong:  DEMO_APP        1   
Error       Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.   DEMO_APP        1   
Error       * Try:  DEMO_APP        1   
Error       Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.  DEMO_APP        1   
Error       Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""D:\My_APP\New folder\Mobile App\DEMO_APP\DEMO_APP\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "D:\My_APP\New folder\Mobile App\DEMO_APP\DEMO_APP\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true" DEMO_APP        1
```

Comment: Which version of the android build tools do you have installed ? I believe you updated to the latest version. All you need to do, is to update your version of JDK to Java 8.

Comment: thanks for suggestion